# Using class library created in vs 2010 into vs 2013 no reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I have a Class Library created in vs 2010.
I have added in a solution created in vs 2013.
When I am trying to use the classed created in Class Library I am not able to do so.
I have added the reference of the project in the where I am using that class Library.

Suppose I have a project name ABC Added the reference and when writing

```
using ABC;
```

It is not able to understand what is `ABC`.

Do I need to create the class library from a scratch or is there any way of achieving it.

Comment: It should be absolutely fine. However, you need to understand that `using` directives specify *namespace* names, not *assembly* names... and only public members of the class library will be visible. Have you got code using the class library working in VS2010? Because that same code should work in VS2013 with no issues...

Comment: @JonSkeet it is working in vs 2010. The above is an example what I am using the namespaces as well like `using CoreModule.Security;` where `CoreModule` is the name of assembly.

Comment: @JonSkeet however what I added a test project and added it's reference I am able to use the namespaces.

Comment: Well, `CoreModule` is *also* the name of a namespace (containing the `Security` namespace) presumably. It's not clear what you've done when you say "I added a test project" - in VS2010? In VS2013? What happens if you open the working-in-VS2010 project in VS2013? Please edit your question with a *lot* more context.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am going to edit my question.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have changed the framework of the class library to same as web project it's working fine now. Thanks a lot !!